# How to add AWS ECS task info as labels with OpenTelemetry

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, open-telemetry

I'm trying to setup monitoring for my ECS services. The idea is to add the `public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:latest` as a second container in each ECS task, and configure it such that it scapes the prometheus endpoint of the application, and then writes it the Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus. I want to add labels to all the metrics to see which ECS service and task the metrics are from. Ideally, to re-use existing grafana dashboards, I want the labels to be named `job` and `instance` for the service 'family' name, and the task id respectively.

I'm using terraform for configuration. The task definition looks like:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = var.name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.task_cpu
  memory                   = var.task_memory
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.task_execution.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.task_role.arn
  runtime_platform {
    cpu_architecture = "ARM64"
  }
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name        = "app"
      image       = "quay.io/prometheus/node-exporter:latest"
      cpu         = var.task_cpu - 256
      memory      = var.task_memory - 512
      essential   = true
      mountPoints = []
      volumesFrom = []
      portMappings = [{
        protocol      = "tcp"
        containerPort = 8080
        hostPort      = 8080
      }]
      command = ["--web.listen-address=:8080"]
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.task.name
          awslogs-region        = data.aws_region.current.name
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name   = "otel-collector"
      image  = "public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:latest"
      cpu    = 256
      memory = 512
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.otel.name
          awslogs-region        = data.aws_region.current.name
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "ecs"
        }
      }
      environment = [
        {
          name  = "AOT_CONFIG_CONTENT",
          value = local.adot_config
        }
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```

And the open telemetry config i'm using looks like:

```yaml
extensions:
  sigv4auth:
    service: "aps"
    region: ${yamlencode(region)}

receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      global:
        scrape_interval: 15s
        scrape_timeout: 10s
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: "app"
          static_configs:
            - targets: [0.0.0.0:8080]

processors:
  resourcedetection/ecs:
    detectors: [env, ecs]
    timeout: 2s
    override: false
  metricstransform:
    transforms:
      - include: ".*"
        match_type: regexp
        action: update
        operations:
          - action: update_label
            label: aws.ecs.task.arn
            new_label: instance_foo
          - action: add_label
            new_label: foobar
            new_value: some value

exporters:
  prometheusremotewrite:
    endpoint: ${yamlencode("${endpoint}api/v1/remote_write")}
    auth:
      authenticator: sigv4auth
    resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
      enabled: true

service:
  extensions: [sigv4auth]
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [prometheus]
      processors: [resourcedetection/ecs, metricstransform]
      exporters: [prometheusremotewrite]
```

However the `foobar` label is added to all metrics, but the `instance_foo` label is not added with the `aws.ecs.task.arn` value. In grafana the labels of `resourcedetection` are visible, but not the `instance_foo` label.

[image]

I did try to debug the open-telemetry application locally, and noticed the `resourcedetection` labels are not yet available in the `metricstransform`.

So is it possible to rename labels using the `metricstransform` that are provided by `resourcedetection`, or are there other ways to set this up?

Comment: ADOT PM here. Thanks for your thoughtful question. Since you're using the sidecar pattern and ingest into Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus, is there a reason why you're not using our [ECS intgration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application-metrics-prometheus.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think what I tried is almost the same as that documentation page describes. The reason I tried to use a custom configuration file is that I wanted to rename some labels, so I can reuse existing Grafana dashboards from https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/. But maybe the best solution for now is to use the `ecs-amp-prometheus.yaml` file and to find/replace all the labels in the Grafana dashboard JSON definitions.